# Excel addition according to neighbour column

Tags: excel, excel-2003, worksheet-function

I've got a time sheet for work in Excel 2003. And I'd like to get a total for the amount of time I've worked on a project. I'm wondering if there's macro or function to get totals from columns that are beside a column with the contents "FCBV" I'll give an example of what I mean... Here's a dummy table. I want to total the durations but ONLY when it's for the project FCBV.

Does anyone know a way to do this? you don't need to give me the full out solution, just ideas, or direction if it's possible. Or if you don't think it can be done. Thanks

```
date     - time  - duration - project - task - details
01/01/12   08:30   0.5        FCBV      W/E    W/E
01/01/12   09:00   1.0        RPEW      W/E    W/E
01/01/12   10:00   0.5        FCBV      W/E    W/E
01/01/12   10:30   0.5        WRSS      W/E    W/E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `SUMIF`?

```
=SUMIF(D2:D4,"FCBV",C2:C4)
=SUMIF(range,criteria,[sum_range])
```

I'm assumeing duration is column C and Project is column D

Answer (score 2):

use pivotTable.

1) Select all --> Insert --> PivotTable --> OK
 Will show new tab
2) Select 
        duration --> Sigma Values 
        Project --> row labels